# Does a compact Kahler manifolds with negative first Chern class admits any nontrivial holomorphic vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, characteristic-classes, holomorphic-bundles

Let $M$ be a compact Kahler manifold with $c_{1}(M)\lt 0$. It seems that I can prove the following claim: there is no nontrivial holomorphic vector field on $M$.

Here is my proof: let $T^{1,0}M$ be the holomorphic tangent bundle, $\Omega_{M}$ be its dual bundle, then
$$c_{1}(\wedge^{n}\Omega_{M})=-c_{1}(M)>0$$
hence

$$\Gamma(M,T^{1,0}M)=H^{0}(M,T^{1,0}M)
=H^{0.0}(M,\Omega_{M}^{*})=H^{n,n}(M,\Omega_{M})^{*}\\
=H^{n}(M,\wedge^{n}\Omega_{M}\otimes \Omega_{M})^{*}=H^{1,n}(M,\wedge^{n}\Omega_{M})^{*}=0 $$

where the third = is due to Serre duality, the last = is due to Kodaira vanishing thm.

I wonder if there is any mistake in my argument, and I don't find any reference about this question. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is right,  you can refer to the fourth Theorem in the following article, saying that the claim you wrote is due to S. Kobayashi.
See [*Ono, Kaoru Some remarks on group actions in symplectic geometry. J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sect. IA Math. 35 (1988), no. 3, 431–437.*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiR9ofLlImBAxXxzDgGHar8CeQQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Frepository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp%2Frecord%2F39445%2Ffiles%2Fjfs350301.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0b-UIiZExcxkYeSMAcb74O&opi=89978449)